# Select preferred launcher pops when lauching JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, junit5, spring-initializr

I have created a Spring Initializr project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkcIr.png)

I import it to Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) - it's OK.

Then I launch JUnit test on my test class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYlyN.png)

Then I have this box popping up when I launch JUint test:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V0Ln.png)

Is it not supposed to be working without any further POM or Eclipse configuration?

The JDK on Window -> Preferences -> Installed JRE is : jdk-11

This is the POM generated by Spring Initializr

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.steph.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know what to try since I expected it to work without any further POM or Eclipse configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's now working with :
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)

I still wonder why Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
needs to parametrize a launcher and also why the process to do so seems not working as well. Spring boot is not exclusively meant for web application so it should work straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now with Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0).

I have reinstalled it, open my spring boot project into it. The JUnit test is running correctly.

I have been comparing the two versions of eclipse configuration and I could not see anything different considering my actual knowledge of Eclipse.

May be it is when I had installed a Liferay plugin that something changed into my previous version of Eclipse and caused damage to JUnit launcher configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).